# Excel VBA-Getting a blank message box with data derrived from an array

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a blank message box for an array which should automatically have and display the following values:

00:00:00

01:00:00

02:00:00
and so on...

Here is my code

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

Dim sampleArr(0 To 24) As Variant
Dim a As Integer
a = 0

Do Until i > 23

    sampleArr(a) = i & ":00:00"
    a = a + 1
    i = i + 1

    MsgBox sampleArr(a)
Loop
```

Please tell me what's wrong with this code

Comment: You are advancing a before using it so you are actually displaying the next blank array element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `Msgbox` first before you increment `a` and `i`.

```
MsgBox sampleArr(a)
a = a + 1
i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You update the value of `sampleArr(a)`, then increment `a`. So to get the just-updated value you need to use the pre-incremented value: `a-1`.

```
MsgBox sampleArr(a-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve here, (especially with `a` and `i` being identical. Presumably the msgbox is only actually in there to prove you've created the array correctly and will be removed later?

That said, as everyone is pointing out, you're incrementing your pointer before displaying the entry. The simplest way to fix that is to put the display line in immediately after creating the element.

I've also formatted `i` in order to produce the exact output you've requested.

Also, I suspect your array only needs to go `0 To 23` if this is some kind of time selector?

So, fixing your issue looks like:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

Dim sampleArr(0 To 23) As Variant
Dim a As Integer
a = 0

Do Until i > 23

    sampleArr(a) = Format(i, "00") & ":00:00"
    MsgBox sampleArr(a)

    a = a + 1
    i = i + 1

Loop
```

However, you could just do the following:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim sampleArr(0 To 23) As Variant
For i = 0 To 23
    sampleArr(a) = Format(i, "00") & ":00:00"
    MsgBox sampleArr(a)
Next
```

Beyond this, if you want to store the values in the array as ***TIME*** rather than a text representation of the time (useful for calculations etc.) then replace the `sampleArr` line with

```
sampleArr(a) = TimeSerial(i, 0, 0)
```

Comment: You are right, this is a time selector for a workbook covering a single day of data and as you've said, the message box is just there to prove that the array is working properly. However, I only need to have this loop until 23:00:00 since 24:00:00 is already equal to 0:00:00. This array will later be used for filtering, searching and to be an input value for a cell therefore I thought it would be better for it to be a String data type.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest just using the For.. Next loop version as it's all you seem to need.